# DELETE Request with Body (Without using Deprecated HttpEntity)

Tags: android, spring, apache, http, http-delete

I wanted to execute a HTTP DELETE request with a Body. I am using Spring Framework.

In order to do that, I had to do the following modification:

```
RestTemplate _deleteManager;
_deleteManager = new RestTemplate();
_deleteManager.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    protected HttpUriRequest createHttpRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
        if (HttpMethod.DELETE == httpMethod) {
            return new HttpEntityEnclosingDeleteRequest(uri);
        }
        return super.createHttpRequest(httpMethod, uri);
    }
});

public static class HttpEntityEnclosingDeleteRequest extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public HttpEntityEnclosingDeleteRequest(final URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "DELETE";
    }
}
```

Then I use the `_deleteManager` to make the call

```
_deleteManager.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, requestEntity, ResponseClass.class);
```

This is working correctly however in the code `HttpUriRequest` and `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase` are marked as deprecated.

What alternative should I use instead? I searched online but couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:** Or a simple answer that shows how to do a DELETE request with a body is enough.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like RestTemplate calls `execute` passing a `HttpEntityRequestCallback` when you do a POST. Could you do the same for DELETE?

Comment: @Kafkaesque I tried it, but it looks like it gets ignored if the method is DELETE. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that with your code above, the `requestEntity` is successfully enclosed as a `body` of DELETE request?

Comment: @BNK With my code above, yes, it works perfectly. Only the deprecation issue I need to solve, or find an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me what is your server? It is said that some servers such as IIS will ignore the body in DELETE request.

Comment: @BNK the server is out of my control and I have no idea what it is sorry. I am working on the client side, the server is configured correctly, because the above DELETE Request is working and I also was able to make a normal request from ios code. The only problem is the android side. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it is just a request's parameter, not the body, isn't it? :)

Comment: Can you test with some tools such as Postman in Chrome?

Comment: @BNK yeah I tested, only way for it to work is using a body. Parameters or headers does not work.

Comment: If so, try using Volley or OkHttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [related topic](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) in the official changelog of the 6.0. So you should use the [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class.

An example:

```
URL url = new URL("your_url");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    // Maybe you should set the request properties here too, but it depends on your body.

    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    osw.write("this_is_the_body");
    osw.flush();

    int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); 
    if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        // Handle the response.
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: This helped me get to the solution so I will give you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

**Option A)** Use [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html)

```
Unirest.delete("http://url.example.com").body("request-body").asString();
```

That's it.

**Option B)** If you do not want to use this library, use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), which is the most widely used http library for Java. However you need to create a small class for delete with body to work:

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
public class HttpDeleteWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "DELETE";
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }
}
```

and use it via:

```
HttpDeleteWithBody request = new HttpDeleteWithBody(url);
request.addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip"); //add some headers if you like
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8"));
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Comment: I was trying not to move to another third party library, it will require a lot of changes for something trivial. as of Option B, that's exactly what I did in my code above, and  HttpClient is deprecated now in Android, that's the whole point of my question. Thanks anyway

Comment: this answer was very enlightening, thanks a lot bekce.